# First VBA Code: Goal Seek Run Time Error 1004

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am a first time user of VBA. I am trying to write a code so that I don't have to run the Goal Seek function 500 times by hand. This is what I have right now:

```
Sub Atkinson2002()
Dim nrow As Integer
nrow = 8
Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & nrow))
'Complete Goal Seek
Range("I" & nrow).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C" & nrow)
nrow = nrow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

The error is coming up in the Goal Seek line. The message says "Run time error '1004': Reference is not valid". I have tried to read through a bunch of posted questions and I can't seem to figure out what is not referenced correctly.

Column C is an estimated temperature

Column I is cells with a formula =abs(C#-H#); where one number is the estimated temperature from column C, and the other is an inputted experimental temperature from column H

Any advice?

Comment: The code works for me with some test data.  I can get a `Reference is not valid` error if either column C or column H contains an error cell, but can't get an error with proper data.  I can also get the error with data in column H that isn't numeric, e.g. "abc" but not with "123".  Try looking at the value of the variable `nrow` when it crashes, and then look at the value in column C and column H of that row.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response. When it crashes the value of column C is being changed by goal seek to some really large number (i.e. 1 x10^13) and therefore altering the value in column H. Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Comment: Column H shouldn't be altered by the goal seek ... unless, perhaps, it is a formula which is referring to either column I or column C ???  What is in column H when you start the goal seek?

Comment: Oh. I am so sorry. What I meant to say was that the value of Column C becomes very large, therefore altering the value of Column I @YowE3K

Comment: Assuming cell H8 is some constant value (e.g. 76.2) and cell I8 is a formula saying `=ABS(C8-H8)`, then a goal seek which changes C8 in order to get as close as possible to 0 in I8 should set C8 to the same value as H8 (i.e. 76.2 in my example).  I'm not sure why it would head off in the direction of positive infinity.  Try running the goal seek manually and see what happens, i.e. whether any error message is generated.

Comment: What kind of values are in column I? Hard coded value or randomize values?

Comment: Column I is a formula which calls on hard coded values @ChaiXiong